# What git command should be used to prepare a branch for a PR?

Tags: git

Hey—I have a question that feels very simple, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it, and attempts to find answers result in answers to a lot of similar-but-subtly-different questions.

I've been working on a feature on an old branch off of master while other teammembers manage a huge pull. Now they're done, and I need to get my feature ready to make a pull request.

I need to take the pertinent changes from my branch (which are spread across 3-4 files across 10-15 commits) and integrate them with the enormous number of changes in master (spread across dozens of files across dozens or hundreds of commits). There are going to be merge conflicts between my versions of the files and their versions, but they'll be easy to resolve. What's the traditional way to catch my branch up (or to make a new branch that combines master + the old branch) and resolve the conflicts? I started to rebase but wound up having to resolve every single commit that had taken place in master since the fork, which seemed totally unnecessary and time consuming.

Thank you!

Comment: Either you merge master into your branch, or you rebase your branch onto master.

Comment: create a patch using commit and apply to new branch

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of doing this is to `git pull master` into your branch and resolve the conflicts. Then `git push` your branch. This makes for less of a headache for the pull request.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in having to sort through a lot of files that are irrelevant to the changes that I made in my branch?

Comment: Git will auto-merge everything that's not a conflict, but yes, you will need to commit them. No way around that unless your pull request process cherry-picks files.

Comment: That seems roundabout—there are merge conflicts in ~100 files, but I only want to deal with 3 of them. In all other cases, I want to defer to master. Is there not a more direct way of doing this?

Comment: In that case, you should create a new branch off master and cherry pick your commits into the new branch. Then submit pull request for new branch.

Answer (score 0):

As [TriskalJM stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886960/2100126) the usual way is to `git pull master` into your branch and `git push` then the PR. However, on your use case, as you said, the `rebase` could get you to deal with conflicts on a per-commit basis. I propose you to check some approaches depending on the actual results.

I think it makes sense to deal with the merges of the `master`branch and the old feature-branch separately of your new changes over the old stuff. For that you may try to cherry-pick just the changes you made on the feature-branch onto a master (or better make a new branch from master, do the cherry-picking on it and merge afterwards with the result to check on it isolated). If it's more clear for you, also you can try instead:

1. Make a new branch from the feature **but from the last commit before your changes**. Let's call it `feature1`.
2. Merge `master` with `feature1`, dealing with conflicts.
3. Cherrypick **your commits** from feature on to `feature 1`.
4. Check results and publish to `master`.

For the `merge` with the feature-branch you may check an option that **is valid too for the simple `rebase` approach that comes to you at first**. The one I refers to is the `strategy` option of the `merge` and `rebase` commands.

By using `git rebase ... -s recursive -X theirs` "**forces conflicting hunks to be auto-resolved cleanly by favoring theirs version**" (being `theirs`=`master` on this case).

**Note 1:** Notice that could be a little bit confusing on the docs, that there is a merge strategy called `ours` and an strategy called recursive with an option called `ours` (or `theirs` as in my proposal). `git merge ... -s ours` <> `git merge ... -s recursive -X ours`